localhost vs web hosting
I have exhausted many possible solutions for setting up cron using a localhost (Local by flywheel, Apache, PHP 8.3.0 WP6.6.2, MySQL 8.0.16) including attempting to change the IP address of my localhost to a static IP, using EasyCrom plugin (can't find the host error).
I have set up gmail by following How to use G Suite / GMail as your CiviMail Provider
Tests of the scheduled jobs (processed email,bounce and email reports) and new mail (test) are apparently successful - but I am not actually receiveing any of the emaild sent from CiviCRM in the receiving email inboxes.
I am wondering if I am wasting my time trying to get this functionality on my localhost site? Should I just try again after moving to a web host site?

Welcome to SE!  If you're planning to move to a web host, I'd do that first - but choose one that accommodates CiviCRM.  Some things are harder on localhost.

I gave up with trying to get cron orking on my Local (Flywheel) PC host. It was too time consuming. So I have set up on a web hsott with C-Panel. Cron and emails are working fine. I'm using the web hosts email service.
